# Qt Check QString to see if it is a valid hex value

Tags: qt, hex, qstring

I'm working with Qt on an existing project. I'm trying to send a string over a serial cable to a thermostat to send it a command. I need to make sure the string only contains 0-9, a-f, and is no more or less than 6 characters long. I was trying to use QString.contains, but I'm am currently stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

### Use QRegExp

Use the `QRegExp` class to create a regular expression that finds what you're looking for.  In your case, something like the following might do the trick:

```
QRegExp hexMatcher("^[0-9A-F]{6}$", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
if (hexMatcher.exactMatch(someString))
{
   // Found hex string of length 6.
}
```

#### Update

Qt 5 users should consider using [`QRegularExpression`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) instead of `QRegExp`:

```
QRegularExpression hexMatcher("^[0-9A-F]{6}$",
                              QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = hexMatcher.match(someString);
if (match.hasMatch())
{
    // Found hex string of length 6.
}
```

### Use QString Only

Check the length of the string and then check to see that you can convert it to an integer successfully (using a base 16 conversion):

```
bool conversionOk = false;
int value = myString.toInt(&conversionOk, 16);
if (conversionOk && myString.length() == 6)
{
   // Found hex string of length 6.
}
```

Comment: For the second solution: wouldn't it be better to use `qlonglong value = myString.toLongLong($conversionOk, 16);` to handle less than 64-bit int's?

Comment: @DavidBurson In this particular case, we're looking for a string with exactly 6 hex characters, which is equal to 6 nibbles (24 bits).  As such, `toInt` is OK on most platforms.  But in the general case, you're right -- `toLongLong` would handle 64 bit values on all platforms.  The regular expression solution could handle even larger values.

Comment: @RA. thanks!  Not sure why I was thinking 1 hex character = 1 byte.  I'd blame it on Monday, except it's Tuesday.